# SQL Injection conundrum

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection

As we know as usual sites use functions like `mysqli_query()` and mysql's PHP driver does NOT allow multiple queries in a `single`->query() call (But you can do as many in ***phpmyadmin*** SQL running section) so we cannot directly add `DELETE/UPDATE/INSERT` but abusing of possibilities to modify data under some circumstances. The 1st thing is that in that case I think 80% of potentially being at risk (maybe lost of data) is gone! & the 2nd one is, rely on this knowledge, why most of injecting tutorials are based and focused on **multiple** queries?

Comment: Are you sure most of tutorial are about multiple query?

Comment: @silentboy, if I trust my eyes, yes

Comment: Then maybe you have seen tutorial from blogs that have just posted 1/2 tutorial in this subject. I think most injecting tuts are based on sanitilizing

Comment: Are you talking of tutorials on protection or *injection*?

Comment: @YourCommonSense: injection, already wrote in text

Answer (score 1):

> 80% of potentially being at risk (maybe lost of data) is gone!

This assumption is wrong.

> why most of injecting tutorials are based on multiple queries?

Because it's just a simple understandable example, a **proof of *concept***. Just like one "If John have 2 apples and Mike five...". If real Mike doesn't feel like to spare his apples, it doesn't mean that arithmetics is all wrong.

> SQL Injection Concudrum

There are NO conundrum in injections.
There is no point in musings on injections.
There is no percents of risk to be calculated but just a dichotomy: either you have your application compromised or not.
There is just one simple rule - always format your data properly, and you will forget of injections forever.

Comment: I didn't say that using multiple queries for demonstrating a `how-to` is wrong and faulty! I said why they concentrate on multiple queries when in real works single queries are the most used ones!

Answer (score -1):

PHP for a long while has disallowed multiple queries running for a single query() statement.  This is just part of preventing sql injection.  You must also escape your inputs, use prepared statements, make your table names and columns hard to guess and such.

The simplest example of an sql injection attack does involve a query that's tricked into executing more than one query, but obviously php prevents a lot of such attacks by the limitation already mentioned.  However, things like subqueries are still possible, so it's not fool proof.  I don't think it's possible to make sql injections altogether impossible as people keep finding new ways to trick scripts.

The best you can do is know how such attacks are done and write your code according to currently accepted best practices to prevent such attacks.  If you've done all this and still get hacked, then probably (but not certainly) it wasn't your sql that was the weakest link in your security.  From what I understand, more often hackers succeed using social engineering techniques.

Making an un-hackable system is nigh impossible, so the best you can do is make it difficult to hack and thus, not be the 'low hanging fruit' or, in other words, don't be an easy target.

Comment: tnx for the answer, I have not enough reputation to downvote, however if I had, I don't downvote either.